# JQuery Ajax Request returns no data

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying out JQuery Ajax methods. I wrote a simple Ajax request to fetch certain 'tagged' photos from Flickr.  Following is the snippet I am using:

```
 function startSearch() { 
      $(function() {
           var tagValue = $("#tagInput").attr("value");
           alert(tagValue);
           $.ajax({
               url: "http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=" + tagValue + "&tagmode=any&format=json&jsoncallback",
               dataType: 'json',
               async: false,
               success: function(data) {
                    alert("Success");
                    $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
                           var pic = item.media.m;
                           $("<img/>").attr("src", pic).appendTo("#images");
                    });
               },
               error: function(data, error) {
                   alert("Error " + error);
               }

     }); });
```

'startSearch' is associated with a Search button.  User is supposed to input a 'tag' to search and on click this function gets called.

Problem is that I am not receiving any 'data' in response.  Hence no images gets displayed.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks & Regards,
Keya

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're trying to make a cross-site request, which doesn't work because of security concern. You could use JSONP instead, e.g. as described in http://www.viget.com/inspire/pulling-your-flickr-feed-with-jquery/

You can also try searching for "cross site ajax" on this site, there's plenty of discussion about it.

Comment: Actually the weird part is that, when I try to do the same thing individually not as a part of "Button Click", I get the Flick feed. 

Does that not fall under the cross-site request?  I am not much familiar with this concept.  I will check out the link.

Regards.

Comment: What do you mean by "individually"? How exactly are you doing that?

Comment: By Individually I mean on page load.  And otherwise I meant as I said earlier, on a button click.